# rsync: large exclusion list adding 10 hours to sync

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync

I have had an rsync backup script running on a Centos 6 box that has been syncing ~410gb of data from a local (LAN) server over a gigabit connection. This script runs hourly, and if there are no new files to copy then it usually takes about 20 mins to complete.

I have implemented a purge script that runs on the Centos box and deletes all files from the local backup copy older than 1 year (after some checks) and adds these files to an exclusion list for rsync to parse. It all works ok, but it's taking about 10 hours to complete (with no new files). After the initial purge the source data is now about 80gb and the exclusion list is about 90mb.

Here's my rsync line from the script:

```
rsync -pad $wholefiles  --exclude-from=${exclfile}.combined /mnt/${smbdir}/${drive}/${foldername} /backup/rob/${smbdir}/${drive} >> /var/log/rob/robso.log 2>&1
```

Does rsync (or bash) have size limitations for file lists? Can you see anything in my syntax that would cause such a huge amount of processing time? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The $wholefiles variable  in the rsync line above passes the --whole-file option in this case.

Comment: Have you disabled the cron job before testing? Check if you have multiple rsync processes running in the background. Check your netIO.

Comment: Thanks, but yes I have, @Kaurin. I also read that rsync 3.0+ offers better speed with large file numbers so I upgraded from 2.68 --> 3.06. Ran last night and it's no faster.

Comment: How are you mounting samba? Fuse = bad, Cifs = good. Fuse has horrible performance.

Comment: I had an issue with long rsync delays with very large folder structures (100k folders, 1mil files). Setting up unison to do a one-direction sync over ssh runs in seconds without updates. The problem for me was that rsync sends the whole file list over the network, regardless if a file has changed. Unison only sends the list of changed files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn this around. Instead of having `rsync` exclude a large number of files I'd not give those files to `rsync` for consideration.

```
cd "/mnt/${smbdir}/${drive}/${foldername}" &&
    find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -366 -type f -print0 |
    rsync -a0 --files-from=- . "/backup/rob/${smbdir}/${drive}" >> /var/log/rob/robso.log 2>&1
```

I'm not entire sure whether by specifying `rsync -d` (`--dirs`) you're intended for there to be no recursion. If I've got this wrong then remove the `-maxdepth 1`.

The `--whole-file` option is irrelevant because that will always be used here, since `rsync` sees that it's copying between two parts of the same "local" filesystem. (Yes, that means its delta algorithm is disabled.)

You may want to reduce timespan for the set of files that `find` considers. Here I've set it to include files that have been modified only in the last 366 days because you mentioned excluding files that are over a year old.